# Calculate the period of validity of the price

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, window-functions

I have a [table](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yvn7uahb) with an item, its cost and the date it was added.

```
CREATE TABLE item_prices (
    item_id         INT,
    item_name       VARCHAR(30),
    item_price      DECIMAL(12, 2),
    created_dttm    DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO item_prices(item_id, item_name, item_price, created_dttm) VALUES
(1, 'spoon', 10.20 , '2023-01-01 01:00:00'),
(1, 'spoon', 10.20 , '2023-01-08 01:35:00'),
(1, 'spoon', 10.35 , '2023-01-14 15:00:00'),
(2, 'table', 40.00 , '2023-01-01 01:00:00'),
(2, 'table', 40.00 , '2023-01-03 11:22:00'),
(2, 'table', 41.00 , '2023-01-10 08:28:22'),
(1, 'spoon', 10.35 , '2023-01-28 21:52:00'),
(1, 'spoon', 11.00 , '2023-02-15 16:36:00'),
(2, 'table', 41.00 , '2023-02-16 21:42:11'),
(2, 'table', 45.20 , '2023-02-19 20:25:25'),
(1, 'spoon',  9.00 , '2023-03-02 14:50:00'),
(1, 'spoon',  9.00 , '2023-03-06 16:36:00'),
(1, 'spoon',  8.50 , '2023-03-15 12:00:00'),
(2, 'table', 30    , '2023-03-05 10:10:10'),
(2, 'table', 30    , '2023-03-10 15:45:00');
```

I need to create a new table with the following fields:

- "*item_id*",
- "*item_name*",
- "*item_price*",
- "*valid_from_dt*": date on which the price was effective (created_dttm price record)
- "*valid_to_dt*": date until which this price was valid (created_dttm of the next record for this product "minus" one day)

I thought it might be possible to start by selecting days on which new entries are added with new prices with such a request:

```
SELECT item_id, item_name, item_price, 
       MIN(created_dttm) as dt 
FROM table
GROUP BY item_price, item_id, item_name
```

that provides me this output:

[image: my aggregating]

The expected output is the following:

| item_id | item_name | item_price | valid_from_dt | valid_to_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | spoon | 10.20 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-13 |
| 1 | spoon | 10.35 | 2023-01-14 | 2023-02-14 |
| 1 | spoon | 11.00 | 2023-02-15 | 2023-03-01 |
| 1 | spoon | 9.00 | 2023-03-02 | 2023-03-01 |
| 1 | spoon | 8.50 | 2023-03-15 | 2023-03-14 |
| 2 | table | 40.00 | 2023-01-01 | 2022-01-09 |
| 2 | table | 41.00 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-02-18 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... | .... |

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Are you saying the select is how you want to populate the new table, except also getting the to date?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select distinct
   item_id,
   item_name,
   first_value(item_price) over (partition by item_id order by created_dttm) as item_price, 
   min(created_dttm) over (partition by item_id ) as valid_from_dt,
   max(created_dttm) over (partition by item_id ) as valid_to_dt
from item_prices
;
```

output:

| item_id | item_name | item_price | valid_from_dt | valid_to_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | spoon | 10.20 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | 2023-03-15 12:00:00 |
| 2 | table | 40.00 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00 | 2023-03-10 15:45:00 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/u4vmHDN6)

Comment: yes, something like this, but need to output the start (valid_from_dt) and end (valid_to_dt) of each new price for a specific item

Comment: Ok, I now do see your expected output, which was missing earlier... ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct. It's only missing the next step:

- retrieving the next "*valid_from_dt*" in the partition <item_id, item_name>, using the `LEAD` function
- subtract 1 day from it

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT item_id, item_name, item_price, 
           MIN(created_dttm) AS valid_from_dt
    FROM item_prices
    GROUP BY item_id, item_name, item_price
)
SELECT *, 
       LEAD(valid_from_dt) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id, item_name) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS valid_to_dt 
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2gdsdNR7c2DUDPy1T3z9N1/0).